Need help in understanding Baron & Besanko (1987) paper "Monitoring, Moral Hazard, Asymmetric Information, and Risk Sharing in Procurement Contracting
I am reading a paper by Baron and Besanko (1987) (https://www.jstor.org/stable/2555639) and I am having a trouble in understanding a particular portion of their math that deals with conditional expectations. Any help is deeply appreciated!
C is the cost function: $C = c(\theta,a)x + k + \sqrt{\alpha}\epsilon$ where "epsilon is the realised value of $\tilde \epsilon$ with mean 0"
$z=C + \sqrt{\beta}\eta$  ($\beta$ is the randomness parameter, "$\eta$ is the realised value of $\tilde \eta$ with mean 0")
$\alpha>0 \beta>0$
They write:
For the case where $\tilde \epsilon$ and $\tilde\eta$ are standard normal, independent random variables, conditional distribution of of cost conditional on z can be written as:
$g(C|z) = N(C|(c(\theta,a)x + k)\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta} + z \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta},\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta})$
where N(.|m,v) denotes normal density function with mean m and variance v.
so, if I am not mistaken, they mean that $E[C|z] =(c(\theta,a)x + k)\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta} + z \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$ and $Var[C|z] =\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}$.
I don't understand how have they calculated this mean and variance. Any help is deeply appreciated. I am absolutely lost here.
I would be grateful if someone who has read this paper would be willing to discuss it with me.

The result is due to properties of normal random variables.
First,

If $X$ and $Y$ are independently normal, then $Z=X+Y$ and $X$ are jointly normal.

Second,

If $X$ and $Z=X+Y$ are jointly normal, then
\begin{equation}
E(X\mid Z) = \mu_X + \frac{\sigma_{XZ}}{\sigma_Z^2}(Z-\mu_Z) 
\quad\text{and}\quad 
\text{Var}(X\mid Z) = \frac{\sigma_X^2\sigma_Y^2}{\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2}
\end{equation}

Applying these to your problem, where $X=C$, $Y=\sqrt\beta\eta$, and $Z=z$ with the following statistics
\begin{align}
\mu_X & = c(\theta,a)x+k \\
\mu_Z & = c(\theta,a)x+k \\
\sigma_X^2 & = \alpha \\
\sigma_Y^2 & = \beta \\
\sigma_{XZ} & = \sigma_X^2 = \alpha \\
\sigma_Z^2 & = \alpha +\beta
\end{align}
we thus obtain
\begin{align}
E(C\mid z) & = c(\theta,a)x+k+ \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}[z - (c(\theta,a)x+k)] \\
& = (c(\theta,a)x+k)\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta} + z\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(C\mid z) & = \frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha+\beta}
\end{align}
